# Implement ASP.NET MVC5 search functionality using 2 tables

Tags: c#, xcode, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created two tables: Claim and ClaimAttachments.
I'm trying to join them on ClaimID in order to get the filtered data from both the tables.

public ActionResult Index(int? search)
{

```
        if (search!=null)
        {
            var Product = (from P in db.Claims
                           join C in db.ClaimAttachments on
                           P.ClaimID equals C.ClaimID

                           select new Claim
                           {
                               ClaimID = P.ClaimID,
                               ClaimBatchID = P.ClaimBatchID,
                               PatientControlNumber = P.PatientControlNumber,
                               PatientFirstName = P.PatientFirstName,
                               PatientLastName = P.PatientLastName,
                               ServiceFromDate = P.ServiceFromDate,
                               ServiceToDate = P.ServiceToDate,
                           });
             return View(db.Claims.Where(x => x.ClaimID == search).ToList());
           

        }
        
        else
        {
            return View(db.Claims.ToList());
        }
```

I'm able to get the searched result but from single table. The join is not working.

Comment: "Not working" in what way, exactly?  What's the actual problem that you're observing?

Comment: Instead of  View(db.Claims.Where(x => x.ClaimID == search).ToList()); do  View(Product.Where(x => x.ClaimID == search).ToList());

Comment: @David, when I'm running the search filter. The result is displayed just from Claims table but I want the combined result from both the tables.

Comment: I did Product.Where(x => x.ClaimID == search).ToList()); as well but still not getting the filtered result from the other table.

Comment: @CodeCademy: It looks like you're only *selecting* from one table: `db.Claims.Where(x => x.ClaimID == search).ToList()`  What other table's data are you expecting to see and why?  Even in the line of code above that, you only ever select any data from the `Claims` table (and then never use the result of that query).  What other table are you expecting to see data from and why?  When you join your tables in that query, what data are you looking to *select* from those two tables?  (Currently you're only selecting from *one* table.)

Comment: @David, right I'm just returning the view from a single table. I'm not able to write the correct view code for both tables. I also tried using View(Product.Where(x => x.ClaimID == search).ToList()); but it didn't work.

Comment: My objective: 

Create sample tables - Claim, ClaimAttachment and ClaimDetails(Will be empty by default) in the database.

Create 1st View page to show the Claims with search functionality, once search the claims user should be able to see the filtered record with edit button.

Create 2nd View page to edit the data in Claims table and store it in ClaimDetails.

By default UpdatedDate will be empty in ClaimDetails table once user updates the record updated date should be populated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're only selecting from the `Claims` data:

```
return View(db.Claims.Where(x => x.ClaimID == search).ToList());
```

You have a `join` query just above that line of code:

```
var Product = (from P in db.Claims
               join C in db.ClaimAttachments on
               P.ClaimID equals C.ClaimID

               select new Claim
               {
                   ClaimID = P.ClaimID,
                   ClaimBatchID = P.ClaimBatchID,
                   PatientControlNumber = P.PatientControlNumber,
                   PatientFirstName = P.PatientFirstName,
                   PatientLastName = P.PatientLastName,
                   ServiceFromDate = P.ServiceFromDate,
                   ServiceToDate = P.ServiceToDate
               });
```

But you don't do anything with the results of that query.  It sounds like you *meant* to use the results of that query (which is in the `Product` variable, which incidentally should probably have a *plural* name since it's a collection) instead of just selecting from `db.Claims`.  Something like this:

```
return View(Product.Where(x => x.ClaimID == search).ToList());
```

Note however that you're still only *selecting data* from *one* table.  Though the `join` operation may alter the results of that selection.  But the selection itself is here:

```
select new Claim
{
    ClaimID = P.ClaimID,
    ClaimBatchID = P.ClaimBatchID,
    PatientControlNumber = P.PatientControlNumber,
    PatientFirstName = P.PatientFirstName,
    PatientLastName = P.PatientLastName,
    ServiceFromDate = P.ServiceFromDate,
    ServiceToDate = P.ServiceToDate
}
```

Notice how every value selected is from the `P` alias, which is defined here:

```
from P in db.Claims
```

So you're successfully joining the two tables, but only selecting data from one of the two tables.  If you want to also select data from the other table then, well, you need to select data from the other table.  For example, if there's a property on that table called `SomeProperty` that you want to select then you'd need to select it, and into an object which *has* that property.

For example, you might create a view model (let's call it `ClaimViewModel` as an example) which represents a combined record of the two tables, containing the properties you want from each.  Then you'd select into that type:

```
select new ClaimViewModel
{
    ClaimID = P.ClaimID,
    ClaimBatchID = P.ClaimBatchID,
    PatientControlNumber = P.PatientControlNumber,
    PatientFirstName = P.PatientFirstName,
    PatientLastName = P.PatientLastName,
    ServiceFromDate = P.ServiceFromDate,
    ServiceToDate = P.ServiceToDate,
    SomeProperty = C.SomeProperty // <--- here
}
```

This would select the *combined* data into a list of `ClaimViewModel` objects, which you'd then filter based on your "search" and return to your view just like you do with the `Claims` objects now.  And of course that view would need to be updated to expect a collection of `ClaimViewModel` objects instead of a collection of `Claim` objects.